# SQL Server : if record found update else insert, merge query error correction

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, merge, insert-update

I have come up with following query for SQL Server for updating a row if found else insert

```
merge tblpermissions  as t
using (select cid, uid from tblpermissions) as s
on (t.cid = s.cid and t.uid=s.uid)
when not matched
THEN INSERT (cid, uid, [read], [write], [readonly], [modify], [admin]) VALUES ('1',   '1', 1, 1, 0, 1, 1) 
when matched 
THEN UPDATE SET [read]=1, write=1, readonly=0, modify=1, admin=1 ;
```

Although it does not throw any error, its not achieving what I expect. there's no record in the table and its not inserting new record.

Any correction?

Edit: Considering your suggestions I have modified it further as below,without any expected result though -

```
MERGE INTO tblpermissions  as t
using (SELECT '1' AS cid, '1' AS uid FROM tblpermissions) as s
on (t.cid = s.cid and t.uid=s.uid)
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
THEN INSERT (cid, uid, [read], [write], [readonly], [modify], [admin])
VALUES  ('1', '1', 1, 1, 0, 1, 1) 
WHEN MATCHED
THEN UPDATE SET [read]=1, write=1, readonly=0, modify=1, admin=1 ;
```

Edit: pls check comment at the bottom, below is the improved query on your suggestions, not to mention it wont work as expected as it takes same table again.

```
MERGE INTO tblpermissions  as t
using tblpermissions as s
on (t.cid = s.cid and t.uid=s.uid)
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
THEN INSERT (cid, uid, [read], [write], [readonly], [modify], [admin])
VALUES  ('1', '1', 1, 1, 0, 0, 1) 
WHEN MATCHED
THEN UPDATE SET [read]=1, write=1, readonly=0, modify=1, admin=1 ;
```

Edit: select-if found update-else insert alternative below -

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ".SQL_PREFIX."permissions\n"
              ."WHERE cid='".$cid."' AND uid='".$uid."'";
    $sth = $this->dbh->query($query);
    $res = $sth->fetch();
    //print_r($res);var_dump($res);
    if(!$res || $res==null)
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO ".SQL_PREFIX."permissions (cid, uid, [read], [write], [readonly], [modify], [admin])\n"
            ."VALUES ('$cid', '$uid', ".implode(", ", $values).")";
        if(!($sth = $this->dbh->query($query)))
            $this->db_error(__('Error inserting user permissions.'),
                $query);
    }else{
        $query = "UPDATE ".SQL_PREFIX."permissions SET ".implode(", ", $sets).";";
        if(!($sth = $this->dbh->query($query)))
            $this->db_error(__('Error updating user permissions.'),
                $query);
    }
```

Edit: Below is the mysql solution for this situation -

> INSERT into tblpermissions (cid, uid, [read], [write], [readonly],
>   [modify], [admin]) VALUES  ('1', '1', 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)  ON DUPLICATE KEY
>   UPDATE [read]=1, write=1, readonly=0, modify=1, admin=1

which simply employs the keyword DUPLICATE KEY. Also would like to highlight again that, there's unique key constraint on cid & uid combination. So what mysql does is, first it simply looks for the combination of cid & uid we are trying to insert, if found updates it else inserts fresh record.

Comment: You merging into `tblPermissions` by selecting from the same `tblPermissions` ?!?!? I would guess **all** rows selected in `s` will **already be** inside `tblPermissions` (since you've selected them from there) - so you'll only ever get the `when matched` part obviously ....

Answer (score 2):

Because the source and target tables are the same, there is never a case of rows not matching. All rows on the tblpermissions are being updated.

In order to insert, the source table (defined with *using*) has to be different from the target table, such as the following examples:

```
merge tblpermissions  as t
using (select cid, uid from otherTable) as s
on (t.cid = s.cid and t.uid = s.uid)

merge tblpermissions  as t
using (select cid, uid from tblpermissions) as s
on (t.cid = s.cid + 1 and t.uid = s.uid + 1)
```

Edit: Since you're using constant values instead of the result of a select from any table, maybe the following would do the trick:

```
merge tblpermissions as t
using (select '1' cid, '1' uid, 1 [read], 1 [write], 0 [readonly], 0 [modify], 1 [admin]) s
on (t.cid = s.cid and t.uid = s.uid)
when matched 
    then update set [read] = s.[read], write = s.[write], readonly = s.[readonly], modify = s.[modify], admin = s.[admin]
when not matched
    then insert (cid, uid, [read], [write], [readonly], [modify], [admin]) values (s.cid, s.uid, s.[read], s.[write], s.[readonly], s.[modify], s.[admin]);
```

Although I think to insert only one row merge is overkill, it would be easier to do the following:

```
if exists (select 1 from tblpermissions where cid = '1' and uid = '1')
update tblpermissions set [read] = 1, write = 1, readonly = 0, modify = 1, admin = 1 where cid = '1' and uid = '1'
else
    insert tblpermissions (cid, uid, [read], [write], [readonly], [modify], [admin]) VALUES ('1', '1', 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
```

I don't think SQL Server has a shorter or more elegant way to perform this, nothing like `on duplicate` from MySQL.

Comment: ok, I get your point but I just want to achieve that - if record with particular id exists then update it else insert new record. In this case cid & uid combination exists then update permissions for them else insert new permissions entry.

Comment: The problem is you're comparing the same combinations of cid and uid with themselves. For example, if tblpermissions contains a row with _cid = 1 & uid = 1_, then it will be compared to the very same row, with _cid = 1 & uid = 1_, and the same goes for every row on the table. In the end, there can't be a particular id that doesn't exist, because you're comparing the same ids with themselves.

Comment: ok, so is it that 'using(some query) as s' defines the source to compare it with target table.

Comment: @jhackspmarrow Exactly. In fact, it doesn't have to be a query, you can use a table directly, such as `using otherTable on a = b`.

Comment: @jhackspmarrow Have you found an answer to this question? If it's what I proposed, can you please mark it as correct? Or else let me know how my answer can be improved or maybe even post your own different answer and mark it as correct.

Comment: all n @dang sorry for delayed reply.ms website explains the syntax for merge at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522%28v=sql.105%29.aspx  I understood it and from your comments as well, that it expects the 'other table' in using clause, but unfortunately this is not what I am looking for.I need to do this operation on 'same table'. So far could not come up with better solution, except the traditional way of selecting record first - if found update and else insert.

Comment: @jhackspmarrow You can merge the same table on itself perfectly fine, you just have to set the merge condition to something that allows different rows to correlate. If cid and uid are the PK for that table, you can't have a different set in the source and target. Can you post your code to select records first and then deciding what to do? Maybe we can help turn it into a merge.

Comment: sorry again @dang for late response, edited the question, pls find the select-n-update alternative above.

Comment: It looks like the values for `cid` and `uid` aren't coming from the table, but from some PHP variables. If that's the case, I suppose it can't be turned into a merge, since the comparison requires data that is not present exclusively from SQL queries.

Comment: ok, but I will keep thinking about this.mysql has its own way to deal with such situation, I wonder why mssql cant provide it.

Comment: What's the MySQL solution to this? Maybe we can think of something similar in SQL Server.

Comment: Ok @Dang, thank you for still showing an interest. included a MySQL  solution above and was trying to figure out MS SQL equivalent for the same.